# Correct way of implementing LiveData

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

In the Android docs it shows an example creating a LiveData object as follows:

```
val currentName: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

But I have seen code elsewhere that shows it like this:

```
val currentName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Both of these are located in the viewmodel. In the second example, the LiveData model is instantiated when the class is created whereas in the first example, it is only instantiated when the object is first used.

Are both of these cases valid?

Comment: I think both are ok. Maybe its just based on personal use, like if there is a lot of configuration changes like rotation, so the livedata is not initialized every time the change happens, then its better to use `lazy`.

Comment: As P.juni said both is fine,  define with `lazy` means the system will allocate the variable memory only when you first time reference it. But second one will allocate  the variable memory immediately when the ViewModel instance create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both of these cases are valid. However, there is a distinct difference between the two. When using `by lazy` it will still set the LiveData object, but it will not set it until the variable is first used. In the case of the second option, it will initialize the LiveData object when parent is created.